# How to make a ssh client ip as proxy

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssh, proxy

I'm not asking for a answer without searching. I already searched everwhere, and as my last try I'm in stackoverflow to see if its really possible.

My problem is, I've a Windows 10 PRO machine, who I need use the IPs address of this machine. I told my self, simple, everything I need is a ssh tunnel. But its hard to configure a full featured ssh server in Windows, because of the system it self. But the client is always easy.

I'm trying creating a reverse ssh tunnel in the client, on my Ubuntu server, but with no success. What I need is a proxy, who uses the ip address of the windows client, who are connecting to my ssh server on Ubuntu to make https requests in curl that are only allowed by the windows machine ip.

I already try everything, including plink.exe, who seems me the best and lightweight solution for make a ssh connection in Windows.

Anyone can help me please?

Thks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

1. A proxy server on the Ubuntu server (squid or else), this proxy server would accessible through for instance port 8080 on the server.
2. Port forwarding in an SSH connection, so that the 8080 port on the server appears as a port on your local machine, for instance 9090 (it could also be the same).
3. On the Windows machine, you declare the proxy as being `localhost:9090`. Connections to `localhost:9090` are forwarded as connections to `server:8080` and so will connect to the proxy on the server.

In practice:

- Make sure that on the server, `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has `AllowTcpForwarding yes`
- At least PuTTY supports port forwarding, it's part of the options in an SSH connection. Of course you have to start an SSH connection to the server with PuTTY before you can use the proxy.

We use a similar setup at work to connect to a DB server. Firewalls only allow connection to SSH so we use this to forward the DB server port to our local development machine where the DB server appears as local port.

Comment: I not haven't tested yet, but just a question. Will HTTPS work with this setup? I ask this, because I always get a ssl error in my lastest setups with squid. The intention here is to use the original certificate of the site, thats why I need the ssh connection it self, so the crawler can get all the assets in the page who are in https.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516323/https-connections-over-proxy-servers